# .append <table> JQuery not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, append

My table is printing fine in Firefox, but is not displaying in IE9.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Please see code below:

```
$("p").append("<br>");
$("p").append("This is printing in IE"); //table is not

$("p").append("<table id=\"course_titles\" class=\"display\" bgcolor = \"#CC0000\" width=\"75%\" cellspacing=\"0\" border = \"1\">");
$("#course_titles").append("<tr>");
$("#course_titles").append("<td><b>Course Title</b></td>");
$("#course_titles").append("<td><b>CU Equivalent</b></td>");   //None of this table is printing in IE, works in Firefox
$("#course_titles").append("<td><b>Subject</b></td>");
$("#course_titles").append("<td><b>ECTS</b></td>");
$("#course_titles").append("<td><b>Credit Value</b></td>");
$("#course_titles").append("<td><b>Course Number</b></td>");
$("#course_titles").append("</tr>");
$("#course_titles").append("</table>");

$("p").append("<br>");
$("p").append("This is printing fine in IE");
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors, or debugged this in any way?

Comment: I created a fiddle and tested in IE9 and seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/rb1ydsk0/

Comment: .html does not work, I tried it.

Comment: @user3182230 not sure what you mean by ".html does not work". Tried the log the `$('p').html()` and it worked fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rb1ydsk0/1/

Comment: The table definition is displaying, the table is empty. ...Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is a problem somewhere else in my code?

Comment: I've isolated this js code and it works by itself.  The table displays in the IE browser. When the js is being called from an oracle stored procedure it does not work.  This is only a problem in IE.  Works fine in Fire Fox.  I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is working fine on my IE9, I would suggest appending the whole HTML with one `.append()' method instead of trying to append the table and try to use selector with its id. It sounds like your IE9 is having troubles finding the appended element most likely appended DOM element not being ready to use:

```
$("p").append('<table id="course_titles" class="display" bgcolor = "#CC0000" width="75%" cellspacing="0" border = "1">'
    +'<tr>'
    +'<td><b>Course Title</b></td>'
    +'<td><b>CU Equivalent</b></td>'
    +'<td><b>Subject</b></td>'
    +'<td><b>ECTS</b></td>'
    +'<td><b>Credit Value</b></td>'
    +'<td><b>Course Number</b></td>'
    +'</tr>'
    +'</table>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rb1ydsk0/2/

Comment: Can u see a better way that I could be approaching this?  Thank u again very much for ur help.      $("p").append('<table id=\"course_listing\" class=\"display\" width=\"100%\" cellspacing=\"0\" border = \"2\">’);
for (var i=0; i<=record.length; i++){
   var equiv_course = $.trim(record[i]);
   var field = equiv_course.split(', ');
   for (var j=0; j<=7; j++){
        element = document.getElementById(field[j]);
        $("#course_listing").append("<td bgcolor=\"blue\">"+field[j]+"</td>");}
       $("#course_listing").append('</tr>' + '</tr>');}
$("#course_listing").append("</table>");

Comment: Ok, are you asking a question?